# pip install -e option requires 1 argument

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am following Flask's official tutorial, and get an error in the [Making the project installable](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/install/#describe-the-project) step. When I run `pip install -e`, I get the following error:

```
Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires 1 argument
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run `pip install -e .` like in the tutorial you are following. The dot after `-e` is part of the command, it indicates the current directory.